# Relative Path to TemplateURL and StyleURL Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-components

I am trying to separate my files inside my Angular 4 project into sub folders.  As many of you may know, once you start adding more and more components, adding `.html` files of the templateURLs can become cumbersome inside a single folder.

I have tried to put my file structure like such:

```
components (folder)
    -- about.component.ts
html (folder)
    -- about.component.html
css (folder)
    -- about.component.css
```

But when I try to use relative paths from the `about.component.ts` file, it throws me an error telling me that the file doesn't exist.

This is the error:
`GET http://localhost:3000/app/components/app/components./html/about.component.html 404 (Not Found)`

Here is what my component looks like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    module: module.id,
    selector: 'about',
    templateUrl: '../html/about.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../css/about.component.css']
})

export class AboutComponent{}
```

I am using commonjs and from reading articles online, `module.id` should solve this problem, but it is still telling me the templateURL and styleURL don't exist when they clearly do.

Thanks for the help!